# Springboot application unable to recover after jms connection failure

Tags: spring-boot, solace

We have a sprinboot application which stops retrying to connect with solace queues after 3 connection attempts. We get below information logged and then application just does not respond and we have to restart the application:

```
2021-09-15 16:49:08.021  INFO 4444 --- [recovery-thread] bitronix.tm.recovery.Recoverer           : recoverer is already running, abandoning this recovery request
2021-09-15 16:50:04.862  INFO 4444 --- [connect_service] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connection attempt failed to host '<<hostname>>' ReconnectException com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPSecurityException: Error performing login to LoginContext (*****) cause: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: *****
2021-09-15 16:50:07.865  INFO 4444 --- [connect_service] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connecting to host 'orig=tcp://<<hostname>>:55555, scheme=tcp://, host=<<hostname>>, port=55555' (host 1 of 1, smfclient 2, attempt 3 of 3, this_host_attempt: 1 of 1)
2021-09-15 16:50:07.877  INFO 4444 --- [connect_service] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Connection attempt failed to host '<<hostname>>' ReconnectException com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPSecurityException: Error performing login to LoginContext (*****) cause: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: *****
2021-09-15 16:50:10.878  INFO 4444 --- [connect_service] c.s.j.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel     : Stale reconnect task, aborting reconnect.
```

Below is our configuration for connecting to solace queues:

```
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.className=com.solacesystems.jms.SolXAConnectionFactoryImpl
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.driverProperties.host=smf://<<hostname>>:55555
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.driverProperties.VPN=<<vpn>>
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.driverProperties.authenticationScheme=AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME_GSS_KRB
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.driverProperties.KRBServiceName=HOST
```

In our service class we are just autowiring the object of jmsTemplate and publishing messages on the queue.

I went through few documentations and tried adding below configuration:

```
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.ignore-recovery-failures=true
```

But still I am facing the same issue. Any suggestions

====Edit

I face this issue only when I put my laptop in airplane mode and reconnect. If I just disconnect from VPN and connect back solace connection is getting reestablished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the various documentations and doing some hit and trials, below properties turn out too be useful. Hope it can help somebody:

```
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.driverProperties.reconnectRetries = -1
spring.jta.bitronix.connectionfactory.driverProperties.connectRetries = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SolXAConnectionFactory` interface allows for you to tune the connect and reconnect parameters. Docs [here](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/jms/com/solacesystems/jms/SolConnectionFactory.html).

You'll want to checkout these and maybe a few others. I suggest searching the javadoc for "retry" and "retries":

- connectRetries
- connectRetriesPerHost
- connectTimeoutInMillies
- reconnectRetries

Comment: Thanks can you please suggest something after my edits in question

Answer (score 1):

I did more research and found the following helpful, would try it in my application : https://solace.community/discussion/917/why-won-t-my-solace-enterprise-application-reconnect-after-an-ha-failover   To set it at JNDI, I think this should also be configured at SolAdmin -> JMS Administration -> connection factory -> Transport Properties.

Comment: Thanks can you please suggest something after my edits in question